# MTurk: Having a separate payment rate for partial survey completion?

Tags: mechanicalturk

Apologies if this is not the right forum for this question:

I have a survey ~10 mins long, with a comprehension check ~3 mins into the survey.

I want to reward participants who complete the full survey with $2, and those who fail the comprehension check with $0.3 (for ex). I want 100 full responses and (if possible) set an upper limit for the number of failed comprehension checks (say not more than 300).

Easiest way to implement this on MTurk?

The only option I can currently think of is to set the base rate as $0.3, and reward those who complete the full survey with a 'bonus' of $2-$0.3=$1.7. This has a few issues:

a) I may get very few workers taking up my survey since the main page will show only a $0.3 reward for a potentially 10 min survey.
b) I want 100 full survey responses - this approach will give me 100 full+partial survey responses.